# if between <pre> tags replace all < with &lt;

Tags: php, regex, expression

I want to replace all the `<` between the pre tags with `&lt;`

I am trying this in php.

So far I have worked this far but am struggling to go any further:

```
preg_replace('\(<pre>)[<](<\/pre>)\', '&lt;', $content);
```

I am using http://www.regexr.com/ to test my expression but so far have failed to find the right expression.

Any help appreciated.

The problem with using htmlspecialchars is that its user input. So i cant tell where in the string or even if they will use the pre tags. but if they do i want these rules to apply. So cant specifically target it.

Comment: No, you don't do this. You never mangle html with regexes. Use DOM. Once you've isolated the "innerhtml" of your pre, THEN you can `htmlspecialchars()` on it and reinsert that snippet into the dom.

Comment: Your question is fundamentally impossible.  What does `<pre>a<pre>b</pre>c</pre>` mean?  You should use Markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no nested `<pre`-tags, I'd use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$str = "<pre>< left < arrow < <</pre>";

$pattern = '~<pre[^>]*>\K.*(?=</pre>)~Uis';

$str = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
         return str_replace("<", "&lt;", $m[0]);
       }, $str);

echo $str;
```

The pattern matches code inside `<pre...>...</pre>`. [Test on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jF6oV8), [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3110638)

- used [modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `Uis`: U (PCRE_UNGREEDY), i (PCRE_CASELESS), s (PCRE_DOTALL)
- [\K](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#k) resets the beginning of the match
- `(.*)` any amount of characters ungreedy (U modifier)
- Using a lookahead to meet `</pre>`

The calback is a simple str_replace `<` to `&lt;`.

Test it on [eval.in](https://eval.in/136076). If it doesn't work, might have an older PHP version, that does not support [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), use a normal function [like this](https://eval.in/136075).

Answer (score 1):

Just use http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php to encode those characters

i.e.

```
 echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($content) . "</pre>";
```

**EDIT**

As the author has saw fit to change the thrust of the question.

Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php to splite the string up and apply `htmlspecialchars` as necessary.

I woujld suggest the regex `<pre/?>`

Answer (score 0):

It is something i would never do, but if needed here is one way to go:

```
$text = "<pre>
last_name, first_name
<bjorge>, philip
kardashian, kim
mercury, freddie
</pre>
adgrgws, apvoih
asvpaiovjas aspvojas ass0voj
<pre>
last_name2, first_name
<bjorge>, philip
kardashian, kim
mercury, freddie
</pre>";

preg_match_all("#\<pre\>(.+?)\<\/pre\>#s",$text,$out);

var_dump($out[1]);

foreach($out[1] as &$val){
$val = str_replace ( '<', '&lt;',$val);
}
var_dump($out[1]);
```